# Calculate percentage of a path segment

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

This problem should be quite simple but I am having a hard time getting to the solution...

Imagine that I have the following path:

```
|--------|-----O--------|
A        B              C
```

Where `O` represents a car. Let's say that the Car is now 60% through the path A-C.
Knowing that B is 40% (regarding A-C), what is the distance (in %) covered on the path B-C?

Comment: The car is on $(60-40)/60 = 33.33\%$ of B-C.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the percentages are distances. A to C is $100\%$, so imagine that it's $100m$ (metres) in distance. A to B is $40\%$ of the distance, so call it $40m$, and so B to C would be $60m$.

If the car has covered $60\%$ of the distance, then the distance from A to the car is $60m$. The distance from A to B is $40m$, so the distance from B to the car is $60m - 40m$ = $20m$.

Then we can divide $20m$ by the distance from B to C to find the $\%$ distance covered from B to C. $20 \div 60 = \frac{1}{3}$, which as a percentage is $33.\dot{3}\%$.

Answer (score 1):

$z$ the position of the car through A-C.
The targeted percentage is : $\frac{z - B}{C-B}$
Why ? Because it's linear and you know that being at B is $0$ and being at C is $1$.
If z stand for the percentage, then $C = 1$ and that is the same formula.